# Excel - How to read cell value exactly as they show up on the spreadsheet, not by formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a process that involves (sometimes manually) cleaning a CSV before I run it through R code. A lot of these CSVs are from other sources so I don't have control over their formats.

I have a column of `Time Remaining` in Minute:Second format with values such as 15:00, 14:32, etc. Excel automatically reads this as a time, so even though "15:00" shows up in the cell, the actual value is "12:15:00 AM". I really need to be able to parse this column into separate Minute/Second columns, but I can't do this because the formats are all funky.

For example, if the "15:00" is in A1, and in B1 I write `=left(A1,2)`, the result is "0.". This is because technically the value of A1 is "0.010416" (15 minutes is .25 of 24 hours => .25/24 = .0104166).

All I want is for the column to be read and manipulated exactly how it shows up in the spreadsheet. Do I have any options given that I'm not the creator of the spreadsheet?

Edit: To clarify, the owner of the spreadsheet sends it with the intention it be read as text "15:00". Excel automatically converts it to a timestamp, which makes it very difficult to work with.

Edit 2: Better yet try this for yourself. Go to a cell and type in "15:12", and you'll see Excel change this to 3:12:00 PM. Using any formula on this cell produces unexpected results. Is there a way to convert the cell to literally what's in the cell itself? I can't just convert it to Text format as that will change it back to a decimal.

Comment: The actual value is NOT "12:15:00 AM". The actual value is a decimal number that Excel interprets and DISPLAYS as a time value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get parts of time:

`=HOUR(A1)`

`=MINUTE(A1)`

`=SECOND(A1)`

Alternatively, reformat as text before using `LEFT`, `MID` or `RIGHT`:

`=LEFT(TEXT(A1,"hhmmss"),2)`

`=MID(TEXT(A1,"hhmmss"),3,2)`

`=RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"hhmmss"),2)`

Answer (score 1):

If the user entered `15:00` into a cell, then Excel will interpret that as a time value, because of the colon, which is typically used in time values. That's just how Excel works.

If you want to move that back into a text value, you can use

```
=text(A1,"hh:mm")
```

In the screenshot you can see the result of that in B1. Since it's text, it's automatically left-aligned, whereas the time value, being a number, is automatically right-aligned.

[image]

If you have the chance to educate the creator of the spreadsheet, you could ask them to prepend the entry with a single apostrophe. This will keep the value as text and will not turn it into a number or a time value.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you’re currently “cleaning” the input file. 
If you want to access the value that’s in the file,
you should clean your “Time Remaining” field
so Excel doesn’t see it as a date/time. 
Simply change `15:12` to `'15:12` or `="15:12"`. 
This is easy to do in `sed`, `awk`, or Notepad++.

Another approach is to format the cells as “Text” before you import the file.